# sorting an alphanum array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

i am trying to compare two arrays containing alphabets and numbers using jquery but a call to the function does nothing.

```
    jQuery.compare = function (string2,string1) {
        alert("comparing")
        var i, j;
        for ( i = 0, j=0; i < string2.length|| j<string1.length; ++i,++j) {

            var n1 = 0,n2=0;
                if ($.isNumeric(string2[i+1])) {
                    num=string2[i]
                    while ($.isNumeric(string2[i+1])) {
                        i++;
                        num += string2[i]

                    }
                    n1 = 1;
                }
                if ($.isNumeric(strin1[j])) {
                    num1 = string1[j]
                    while ($.isNumeric(string1[j+1])) {
                        j++;
                        num1 += string1[j]
                    }
                    n2 = 1;
                }


                if (n1 == 1) {
                    if (n2 = 1) {
                        if( parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num) !=0)
                            return parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num);
                    }
                    else
                        return 1;
                }
                else if (n2 = 1)
                    return -1;
                else {
                    if(string2[i]-string1[j]!=0)
                       return string2[i]-string1[j]!=0;

                }
        }
        if (j < string1.length)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;

    }
```

Also i would like to know the best way to call this function. I would like to use something like string1.compare(string2) and replace string1 with 'this' in the above code fragment.

EDIT:
This is how i call the compare function.Here, colValues is an array of string.

```
    $.fn.sort = function (colValues) {
        alert("sorting")
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < colValues.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
                alert("before compare")

                if(colValues.compare(colValues[j],colValues[j + 1])) {
                    var temp = colValues[j];
                    colValues[j] = colValues[j + 1];
                    colValues[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return colValues
    }
```

if i replace

```
    if(colValues.compare(colValues[j],colValues[j + 1]))
```

with

```
    if(colValues[j]>colValues[j+1])
```

my sort function works.

i am a complete newbie at coding in jquery. There is probably some syntactical error. I dont really want any help with the algorithm just the syntax.

[jsfiddle-checkout my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/thunderbird/RsEuZ/8/)

EDIT2:
i fixed everything thx to metadings.
heres what i had to change

1)

```
    jQuery.compare
```

to

```
    $.fn.compare
```

2)

```
    if($.isNumeric(string2[i+1]))
```

to

```
    if(jQuery.isNumeric(string2[i + 1]))
```

somehow the

```
     while ($.isNumeric(string1[j+1]))
```

syntax worked without any changes

3)

```
parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num)
```

didnt work either as it returned NaN. To solve this problem i defined two var variables 'number1' and 'number2' and initialized them with 0's and assigned  parseInt(num1) individually to the variables and then subtracted the new variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare". I think you need to be a bit more specific... What's not working? Can you post a live example?

Comment: i edited the problem with some more details. Hope i can get some help now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thunderbird/RsEuZ/8/

Comment: you have there a typo `strin1`, in the 2. `if ($.isNumeric`. In jsFiddle have a look for jsHint, that will show you many syntactical errors, like missing semicolons etc.

Comment: fixed all the errors(mainly semicolons and radix which are not really required)...the code still doesnt work. can you check the code in sort() where compare() is called and also the function compare() declaration syntax. click on any cell of the table column 'name' to check if the code is working.it should show you a series of alert messages.

Comment: I'm sorry not to re-work your entire code. However `colValues` is a jQuery object and not a real Array object, so you need to define `$.fn.compare` and use it using `colValues.compare`. But I don't believe that makes your code fully working at all. Please try to make a real javaScript function, as a newbie you should not start to mess around with jQuery 'plugin' syntax.

Comment: $.fn.compare with colValues.compare resulted in a successful call. that was all i needed. yea i have just begun to use jquery and javascript and this is normally how i learn new stuff. thanks a lot for the help. i actually had started with $.fn.compare but i was probably not calling it correctly.

Comment: Please notive that `$.fn.sort === Array.prototype.sort` by default. I don't think it will help much to overwrite it…

Comment: nah i just wanted to define my own sort function so that strings such as "z2" is sorted before "z100" in ascending order.